# Better way to execute join query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Currently I have two tables; Users and Employees

All users are employees but not all employees are users,

I have a models `Users` and `Employee`, the personal details of a **user** are pulled his respective **employee** record.

Now I wanted to display all **users** and I can do it using `User::all();`
but also I wanted to have their personal details too.

currently I'm doing a `DB::` call to join table in a function on my Users Model.

is there a better approach to this?

Comment: Are your `Employee` and `User` models Eloquent? If so, are they related with an Eloquent relation?

Comment: I'm new to laravel, yes they are eloquent but I havent established an eloquen relation, please propose your solution, really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the Laravel way - eager load the relationship

```php
$users = User::with('employee')->get();
```

This assumes that you have your relationships defined, at least on `User` side.

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Employee;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'employee_no');
    }
}
```

FYI the Laravel way doesn't necessarily mean the fastest or the best way. It's usually syntactically more expensive/terse and convenient though.

Eager loading a relationship requires an additional query. In your case two queries will be executed under the hood and then employee property will be materialized for each `User` model in a collection.

So your way with a `join` and one roundtrip to the database might be more performant at the end of the day.

Comment: I got error, its looking for `user_employee_no` which doesn't exists, my primary keys for both tables are only `employee_no`. How would I stop laravel to add user_ prefix from relationship access

Comment: You can tell Laravel what foreign and local keys to use in the the relationship (2nd and 3rd parameters accordingly) `return $this->hasOne(Employee::class, 'employee_no');` See updated answer

Comment: thanks sir for the answer and also for the insight about join, I was planning to join the `user` table to `user_meta` table which contains access restriction, also `employee` to `employee_meta` for additional optional infos

Comment: hello sir, this might not be related to the question but, how can I display the user table's employee_no, the `{{ $user->methodname->employee_no }} works as it pulled the employee_no from the table employee, but not in table user.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :). If you have `employee_no` in the `User` model you should be able to just to access it directly `$user->employee_no`.

Answer (score 1):

You should establish a relation. In this case your users can relate to your employees as such

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employee::class);
}
```

With Eloquent, you can just define methods in your `User` model to access the relation and be done with it.

```
public function role
{
    return $this->employee->role;
}
```

However, when fetching users, you want to ensure you "eager load" your employee relation so that you're not individually fetching employees when using these methods. When you fetch your users:

```
User::with('employee')->all()
```

If you will always require the employee record you can eager load by default:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $with = ['employee'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use an [Eloquent One to One Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
    }
}
```